# Hide the excerpt and re show it when re toggled

Tags: jquery

I have done my best to do this,.. took me hours still i cant get it to work. 
When readmore is clicked it hides the excerpt and shows the full content, then re names the buttons to HIDE, then when hide is clicked again, it has to show the excerpt again and hide the full content.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/czW8z/3/)

jQuery Code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery('.testi-more').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var same = jQuery(this).closest('.testi-wrapper');
        jQuery(this).closest('.testi-wrapper').children('.testi-full').slideToggle('slow');
    });

    if (jQuery('.testi-full').is(": hidden")) {
        jQuery(this).closest('.testi-wrapper').children('.testi-excerpt').show();
        jQuery(this).closest('.testi-wrapper').children('.testi-more').html('Read moar');
    } else {
        jQuery(this).closest('.testi-wrapper').children('.testi-excerpt').hide();
        jQuery(this).closest('.testi-wrapper').children('.testi-more').html('Hide');
    }
});
```

Kindly optimize my code then explain why, so i can study it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you're looking for

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.testi-more').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).text(function(_,txt) {
            return txt == 'Read more' ? 'Hide' : 'Read more';
        }).closest('.testi-wrapper').children('.testi-full')
          .slideToggle('slow').end().children('.testi-excerpt').slideToggle();
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/czW8z/9/)

It toggles the sliding and it also toggles the text with a callback where the current text is checked, and another text is returned depending on what the current text is etc.

Comment: it has to hide the excerpt.

Comment: Yes~! thanks,,, but this is more optimized i think http://jsfiddle.net/decx/czW8z/11/

Comment: @vinex08 - It's at least easier to read, I would still use a callback for html(), like this -> http://jsfiddle.net/czW8z/12/